# How to load a select option using Materialize

Tags: javascript, select, materialize

I´m trying to use a dinamic select with the Materialize framework, but I can´t get the the expected result.

After the page loads, if you change the first select (the fixed one) we can not the all options on the dinamic select. I made a simple example to ilustrate the issue:

***Without Materialize***

```js
//ready function -------------------------
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        startDinamicSelect();
    }); 

    
    // Creating the function to add on listener
    function startDinamicSelect() {
        // Numbers array
        var numbersList = {
          1 : ['1','3','5','7'],
          2 : ['2','4','6','8'],
          3 : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'],
        }
    
        // Adding function to onChange event
        document.querySelector('#fixedSelect').addEventListener("change", function(){
    
        // Get values of the object
        var items = numbersList[this.value];
          
        // Cleaning select
        var selectDinamico = document.querySelector('#dinamicSelect');
        selectDinamico.innerHTML = '';
    
        // Addinng the items as selected on the first select
        items.forEach(function(item){
            var option  = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = item;
            option.text = item;
            selectDinamico.appendChild(option);
          });
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px;margin-top: 10px;">
    
    <html>
    Type:
      <select name="fixedSelect" id="fixedSelect">
        <option value="" selected></option> 
        <option value="1" >Odd numbers</option> 
        <option value="2" >Pair numbers</option>
        <option value="3" >Both</option>
      </select>

     <hr>

    Number:
      <select name="dinamicSelect" id="dinamicSelect"></select>

    </html>
</body>
```

After add the Materialize framework, the dinamic select does not work correctly. Just show the first option and wh can not change the selection

**With Materialize**

```js
//ready function -------------------------
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        startDinamicSelect();
        
        $('select').formSelect();
    }); 

    
    // Creating the function to add on listener
    function startDinamicSelect() {
        // Numbers array
        var numbersList = {
          1 : ['1','3','5','7'],
          2 : ['2','4','6','8'],
          3 : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'],
        }
    
        // Adding function to onChange event
        document.querySelector('#fixedSelect').addEventListener("change", function(){
    
        // Get values of the object
        var items = numbersList[this.value];
          
        // Cleaning select
        var selectDinamico = document.querySelector('#dinamicSelect');
        selectDinamico.innerHTML = '';
    
        // Addinng the items as selected on the first select
        items.forEach(function(item){
            var option  = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = item;
            option.text = item;
            selectDinamico.appendChild(option);
          });
      $('select').formSelect('destroy');
        });
        
    }
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<body style="margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px;margin-top: 10px;">
    
    <html>
    Type:
      <select name="fixedSelect" id="fixedSelect">
        <option value="" selected></option> 
        <option value="1" >Odd numbers</option> 
        <option value="2" >Pair numbers</option>
        <option value="3" >Both</option>
      </select>

     <hr>

    Number:
      <select name="dinamicSelect" id="dinamicSelect"></select>

    </html>
</body>
```

I´ve tried to use with no results

```
$('select').material_select('destroy');

$('select').formSelect('destroy');
```

Some one could tell what´s wrong? Where is the problem the code does not work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I´ve solved this trouble adding a trigger to listen the contendChanged

```js
    //ready function -------------------------
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        startDinamicSelect();
        
        $('select').formSelect();
    }); 

    
    // Creating the function to add on listener
    function startDinamicSelect() {
        // Numbers array
        var numbersList = {
          1 : ['1','3','5','7'],
          2 : ['2','4','6','8'],
          3 : ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'],
        }
    
        // Adding function to onChange event
        document.querySelector('#fixedSelect').addEventListener("change", function(){
        
    
        // Get values of the object
        var items = numbersList[this.value];
          
        // Cleaning select
        var selectDinamico = document.querySelector('#dinamicSelect');
        selectDinamico.innerHTML = '';
    
        // Addinng the items as selected on the first select
        items.forEach(function(item){
            var option  = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = item;
            option.text = item;
            selectDinamico.appendChild(option);
          });
      
          
    //NEW CODE ADDED -----------------------
        $("#dinamicSelect").trigger('contentChanged');        
          
        });
        
        

  // NEW CODE ADDED
  $('#dinamicSelect').on('contentChanged', function() {
    $(this).formSelect();
  });



    }
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<body style="margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px;margin-top: 10px;">
    
    <html>
    Type:
      <select name="fixedSelect" id="fixedSelect">
        <option value="" selected></option> 
        <option value="1" >Odd numbers</option> 
        <option value="2" >Pair numbers</option>
        <option value="3" >Both</option>
      </select>

     <hr>

    Number:
      <select name="dinamicSelect" id="dinamicSelect"></select>

    </html>
</body>
```